# Sequelize query Performance issues with associations

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to upgrade a Node app from Sequelize v3 to v6 that uses a Mysql db.  The queries involving model associations/relationships are much slower on v5/v6 than they are on v3/v4. It almost seems like Sequelize isn't using the table indexes when doing inner or outer joins?  Or is there some other change in v5 I'm missing to speed up queries on model relationships?  Whether using node 10/12/14 doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can log query generated by Sequelize, run with EXPLAIN ANALYZE and check if indexes are used.

Comment: Thanks, after running the same app with sequelize 3 and sequelize 6 side by side, I see about a 200+ms performance difference with a findAll query that has a belongsTo relationship.  For some reason, the sequelize 3 version is much faster, and becomes more apparent when doing a Promise.All with multiple findAll queries that have relationships.  The Explain Analyze output for both queries looks similar and shows that the foreign key is used.  Any other ideas?